# I and Some Users Can't Login to My Web Application, How Can I Fix It?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

Good day house. This is the second time I got locked out of the web application I am working on. It's still being developed on my localhost (laptop) using PHP and MySQL. Please what could be responsible for this? I have been on the project for some months now but got locked out now within the space of 2 weeks. No new plugin or third party stuff. What exactly could be responsible for this? The only thing that has changed is my PHP version(the previous and current is still PHP7, just a minor upgrade). What should I look out for?

I have few other users who can log in and few who can't just like me, so the problem is not with the login code. I have been login in and out before being shut out suddenly with no apparent reason while others can still login. It's not a code problem I guess.

Here is my login code

```
require_once '../classes/DbManager.php';

$error = array();

if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'login') 
{
   //Validate/Sanitize the user input
   $username = filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
   $password = filter_var($_POST['password'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
   
   if(empty($username))
   {
       $error[] = 'The username field cannot be left empty';
   }
   
   if(empty($password))
   {
       $error[] = 'The password field cannot be left empty';
   }
   
   if(empty($error))
   {
      // start the session
      session_start(); 
      
        // connect to the database
        $conn = DbManager::getConnection();
        //Get the hash from the database
        try{
        $sql = "SELECT hash FROM users WHERE username = :username";

        $st = $conn->prepare($sql);
        // bind variables when executing statement
        $st->bindValue(':username', $username);
        $st->execute();
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
        $error[] = 'Invalid username or password.';
        }
        // if a match is found, rowCount() produces 1, which is treated as true
        
       if($st->rowCount() == 1) 
        { 
            $row = $st->fetch();
            $hash = $row['hash'];
        }
        
        // connect to the database
        $conn = DbManager::getConnection();
        //Now connect to log the user in
        try{
        $sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = AES_ENCRYPT(:password, :hash)";

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        // bind variables when executing statement
        $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);
        $stmt->bindValue(':password', $password);
        $stmt->bindValue(':hash', $hash);
        $stmt->execute();
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
        $error[] = 'Invalid username or password.';
        }
        // if a match is found, rowCount() produces 1, which is treated as true
        
        
       if($stmt->rowCount() == 1) 
        { 
            $row = $stmt->fetch();
            $username = $row['username'];
           
        $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = TRUE;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        
        session_regenerate_id(true);
        }

        // if no match, destroy the session and prepare error message
        else {
        $_SESSION = array();
        session_destroy();
        $error[] = 'Invalid username or password.';
        }
        
        
        // if the session variable has been set, redirect
        if (isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])) {
        // get the time the session started
        $_SESSION['start'] = time();

        $login = TRUE;

        header('Location: ../my-account/');
        exit();
        }
        else
        {
    header('Location: .');
    }
   }
   
}
```

Comment: Got any special characters in your user name or password that are getting hit by filter_var()?

Comment: Since you are working on localhost (dev machine) then you should have error_reporting = 0 set in php.ini. This will show coding errors. Secondly, you do not need to open the database connection with each query. If this is your practice on other pages then you could be hitting the db connection limit.

Comment: @ajCary, I don't have any special character in my username. The username had been in use for months and worked just fine. The first time this happened, I deleted my self and re-registered and all began to work well till yesterday when I got shut out again. could it be session problem?

Comment: @jeff, I did that and no error was shown.

Comment: Could any of the warnings in [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php)  apply here?

Comment: @ajCary, thank you for the session_regenerate stuff. From what I read, I think that is where the problem is coming from.